# how to convert a string array to a boolean array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, boolean

I have a list of objects that gets returned from the font end as

```
item=["false","true"]
```

i take these items to check a column from my records to see which values contain true or false as follows

```
this.records.filter(x=> items.includes(x.column))
```

but my records are always returning empty.

if i hard code it as example `this.records.filter(x=> x.column == false)` it works.

But i am using includes() because a user can select both true or false options and i cant go hard code it cause i wont know what the user might select.

how do i convert the string ["true","false"] into [true,false]?

i tried declaring items as

```
public items:boolean[]=[];
```

but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it using `items.map(item => item === "true")`